# How do I set the channel_ id to a function in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
def get_channel_id(client, message):
    with open('./json/welcome.json', 'r') as f:
    channel_id = json.load(f)
    
    return channel_id[str(message.guild.id)]


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x767429, description=f"Welcome to my server! You are the {len(list(member.guild.members))}th member ")

    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f" {member.avatar_url} ")
    embed.set_author(name=f" {member.name} ", icon_url=f" {member.avatar_url} ")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{ member.guild }", icon_url=f" {member.guild.icon_url} ")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    channel = client.get_channel(id=get_channel_id) 

    await channel.send(embed=embed)


@client.command()
async def welcomechannel(ctx, channel_id):
    with open('./json/welcome.json', 'r') as f:
        id = json.load(f)

    id[str(ctx.guild.id)] = channel_id

    with open('./json/welcome.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(id, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f'Welcome channel changed to {channel_id}')
```

I'd like to have the `get_channel_id`function be the ID of the `channel = client.get_channel(id=get_channel_id)` but everytime I run it i get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`. Can someone please help me

Comment: You need to open the JSON after a member joined and then get the channel out of the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code quite a bit. As mentioned in my comment, you also need to open the JSON when a new user enters the server.

Your own function above is completely redundant and not needed.

I also once changed your `welcomechannel` command a bit because you don't get far with `channel_id`, you can use `channel: discord.TextChannel` instead and it comes out the same.

**Here is the command for now:**

```py
@client.command()
async def welcomechannel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel): # We use discord.TextChannel
    with open('./json/welcome.json', 'r') as f:
        id = json.load(f)

    id[str(ctx.guild.id)] = channel.id # Saving JUST the ID, you also had <#ID> in it

    with open('./json/welcome.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(id, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f'Welcome channel changed to `{channel}`')
```

And now to check the channel. For that we open the JSON in the same way as we did with the command:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('./json/welcome.json', 'r') as f:
        wchannel = json.load(f) # Define our channel
    try:
        if wchannel: # If a channel is set for the server
            wchannelsend = member.guild.get_channel(wchannel[str(member.guild.id)]) # Get the channel from the JSON
            embed = discord.Embed(color=0x767429,
                          description=f"Welcome to my server! You are the {len(list(member.guild.members))}th member ")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url} ")
            embed.set_author(name=f"{member.name} ", icon_url=f"{member.avatar_url} ")
            embed.set_footer(text=f"{member.guild}", icon_url=f"{member.guild.icon_url} ")
            embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

            await wchannelsend.send(embed=embed) # Send the embed to the channel
        else:
            return # If no channel was set, nothing will happen
    except:
        return
```